# PHP use variables in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I am setting an array up like this...

```
public function setup_array()
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => '2014-01-24',
        'date2' => '2014-02-14',
        'date3' => '2014-03-11',
        'date4' => '2014-04-01'
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

This works but what I would like to use variables that are already set in place of the dates like so...

```
public function setup_array()
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => '$date1',
        'date2' => '$date1',
        'date3' => '$date1',
        'date4' => '$date1'
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

I have tried to do this an although the $date variables are avaliable and set, it actually prints $date1 instead or retrieving the variable value itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'date1' => $date1` - no quotes

Comment: Your $date1 variable will need to be accessible from within the scope of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes

```
    public function setup_array($date1)
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => $date1,
        'date2' => $date1,
        'date3' => $date1,
        'date4' => $date1
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why you did it

Answer (score 4):

1. Single quotes will cause to interpret string as it is, literally. use double-quotes.
2. Without any passed parameter - `$date1` is unknown inside function scope and, thus, would not be substituted.

   ```
   public function setup_array($date1)
   {
       $columns = array(
           'date1' => $date1,
           'date2' => $date1,
           'date3' => $date1,
           'date4' => $date1
       );
       return $columns;
   }
   ```
3. In your case even double quotes aren't needed since you're using variable as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes

```
public function setup_array($date1)
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => $date1,
        'date2' => $date1,
        'date3' => $date1,
        'date4' => $date1
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Single quotes

```
public function setup_array()
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => $date1,
        'date2' => $date1,
        'date3' => $date1,
        'date4' => $date1
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
$expand=1;$either=2;
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either

echo "Variables do not $expand $either";
// Outputs: Variables do not 2 1
```

More Details [String PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: ...and add double. hilarious

Comment: Mmm doing the same thing twice expecting different results.. I know a definition for that :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand PHP syntax

Quotes in your first example don't mean "something that is used as array value" but regular string delimiters. I.e. these quotes belong to strings, not to array.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that \DateTime does not have a __toString() method, so if $date1 is an instance of \DateTime, you must call `$date1->format('Y-m-d')`

```
public function setup_array($date1)
{
    $columns = array(
        'date1' => $date1->format('Y-m-d'),
        'date2' => $date1->format('Y-m-d'),
        'date3' => $date1->format('Y-m-d'),
        'date4' => $date1->format('Y-m-d'),
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

otherwise it'd throw an \Exception in the event of echoing or casting to string..
if $date1 is scalar you can use double quotes "$date1" and it should still work.
See [[http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php]](http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php%5d)